# read-only derby database freezing

Tags: java, jar, derby

When I make a connection to my read only database, which is now inside of a jar, I can run the application, but when I try to run a query, it freezes the application. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, I followed [this guide](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/dev/devguide/cdevdeploy15325.html)

This is how I'm connecting to the database

```
try
{  
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
    connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:jar:(database.jar)MyDbTest;");
    statement = connection.createStatement();
}
catch (Exception e) 
{  
    e.printStackTrace();  
}
```

Comment: do you have set the "derby.storage.tempDirectory" and "derby.stream.error.file" properties to a writeable temp directory?

Comment: @Sascha that's probably it.. how would I set the directory to right outside the jar file? I want this to work on windows and mac, so I don't want to put it somewhere like C:// or /usr or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So here is my simple setup, where I set the necessary temp dir properties.

```
private static void accessReadOnlyJar() {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver").newInstance();
        Properties props = new Properties();
        String tempDir = System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir");
        props.setProperty("derby.storage.tempDirectory", tempDir);
        props.setProperty("derby.stream.error.file", tempDir+"derby_error.log");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:jar:(data/db.jar)derbyDB", props);

        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM TESTTABLE");
        while(result.next()){
            System.out.println(result.getString("NAME"));
        }

        connection.close();
    } catch (InstantiationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

good locations for your tempDir might be:

- the Systems temp dir: `System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")`
- your working directory: `"."`
- your apps directory: `ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath()`

or anything relative to it ;-)

If this doesn’t solve your problem, check/recreate your database. If it wasn't shut down 
well before you packed your jar, derby will always try a recovery on boot.

Comment: I guess my database wasn't shut down properly, but I did exactly what it said in the guide, and used the same options for the terminal command. Any ideas?

Comment: to shutdown your db, commit all transactions and call `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:MyDbTest;shutdown=true");` see: [DerbyTut](http://db.apache.org/derby/papers/DerbyTut/embedded_intro.html#shutdown)